# Grouping by day + events spanning several days

Tags: views, datetime

This is a question that has already been asked on Drupal.org. It's exactly what I need on my view, but it hasn't been answered yet.

```
Posted by Amanda-333 on April 12, 2011 at 5:58am
I wanted to ask how I can group events by day in a view.

It works fine if I only have events that have their start- and endtime on the same day.
2011-04-12
2011-04-12 10:00 – 2011-04-12 18:00 Event 1
2011-04-12 12:00 – 2011-04-12 14:00 Event 2

2011-04-13
2011-04-13 10:00 – 2011-04-13 18:00 Event 5
2011-04-13 12:00 – 2011-04-13 14:00 Event 8

The problem: I have some events that take several days or weeks.
Example: I create one event with the start date of 2011-04-12 10:00 and the end date of 2011-04-15 19:00 for example.

This event now shows up in the grouped view as
2011-04-12 - 2011-04-18
2011-04-12 10:00 - 2011-04-15 19:00 Event 11

I would like to have that event sorted into the regular day groups (split that event into day parts):
2011-04-12
2011-04-12 10:00 - 2011-04-15 19:00 Event 11

2011-04-13
2011-04-12 10:00 - 2011-04-15 19:00 Event 11

2011-04-14
2011-04-12 10:00 - 2011-04-15 19:00 Event 11

2011-04-15
2011-04-12 10:00 - 2011-04-15 19:05 Event 11

Similar to how it is done in the calendar – day view. But with a simple text list format.
I can not find a way to do this? Perhaps someone can give me a little help?
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/1124616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 2 or 3 computed view fields (which will require some php):

- 1field for `day of event`
- 1 or 2 fields for start time and end time dates.

You can group the View output by the first field. Then create the event time range by inlining the 2 other fields.

With these 3 pieces of info the calendar should be able to see the start and end datetimes and make a line representing the event duration.

Comment: I've thought about that, but say the event is spanning 3 days, how do you get the computed field to output all 3 days of the event that it spans for it to be sorted?

Comment: Also, he's not looking to visually represent the duration - it appears he needs a list view, and the multi-day to create an instance on each day that the event spans.

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks so much!
Attached are my gists for the fields:
https://gist.github.com/johnny5th/eb10748124641121eb12
https://gist.github.com/johnny5th/5d36d91169e7d4160316